# Import error with tensorflow after following all the dowload steps

Tags: python, opencv, download, tensorflow

I was on a robot class so i need both opencv and tensorflow, so i dowloaded both of them on window 10 64-bit. this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
#code here
```

which return this trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/SignClassifer/.idea/source_code.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i was following those steps for downloading tensorflow with GPU for python on window. The "native" pip way: running this command:

```
C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

It downloaded and installed fine. But when i try to import tensorflow this error happened, in an attempt to fix this error i also downloaded a tensorflow GPU packet with pycharm, doesnt seem to be any better, i ve looking all over the internet, doesnt seem to find anything.

Comment: Did you try with the command they provide on [the installation guide for Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#pip_installation_on_windows) ?

Comment: Thank you (i ve been waiting for so long for a respond), no i didnt, let me try it out. EDIT: after trying that commmand, it only update the tensorflow (it said that the tensorflow i currently use is up to date) and fix nothing...

Comment: You could also try running [this script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c). It might give you more details on your problem.

Comment: some how the code fixed it, thank you very much, now all i need is downloading CUDA. `TensorFlow successfully installed.
The installed version of TensorFlow includes GPU support.

Process finished with exit code 0`